# install artwiz fonts in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, fonts

I am trying to install the artwiz fonts in ubuntu 12.04 and following this [thread](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-install-artwiz-fonts-in-ubuntu.html). But xfonts-artwiz2 package doesn't exist in 12.04. Also the thread is too old!

I am trying to install the [osnap font](http://www.deviantart.com/users/outgoing?http://sourceforge.net/projects/osnapfont/) . How can I install this font in 12.04?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a step-by-step in terminal

```
$ cd /usr/share/fonts
$ sudo mkdir myfonts
$ cd myfonts
$ sudo wget -O- downloads.sourceforge.net/project/osnapfont/ohsnap-1.7.4.tar.gz?r=http://sourceforge.net/projects/osnapfont/&ts=1336734212&use_mirror=iweb | sudo tar -xz
$ cd ohsnap-1.7.4
$ sudo mkfontdir
$ sudo xset fp+ /usr/share/fonts/myfonts/ohsnap-1.7.4
$ sudo xset fp rehash
```

That should do the trick!

You can test them out by running, e.g.:
`xterm -fn -*-ohsnap-*-*-*-*-17-*-*-*-*-*-*-*`

Use `xfontsel` to come up with the appropriate font string.

---

Screenshot of `xterm` running ohsnap font:

[image: xterm running ohsnap]

Comment: I did what you have mentioned above, but I can't see the font listed when i go to terminal edit profile (choose fonts)

Comment: Please see edits. These don't work in the default Terminal (Gnome-terminal) by design; those applications use Truetype/Opentype fonts. They only work in pure-X11 applications like `xterm`, or `rxvt`.

Comment: yeah, it only works on xterm not on gnome terminal. Thanks that worked!