# How to install Artwiz Lime?

Tags: 13.04, fonts

I am new to Linux and i want to install a font called: lime. 
Can anyone explain how to do that?

I see that they arent in the repos anymore.

[install artwiz fonts in ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135437/install-artwiz-fonts-in-ubuntu-12-04)
only explains how to install snap.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can obtain an old debian package that still has it [here](http://archive.debian.net/woody/all/xfonts-artwiz/download)

You should be able to install it with software center

Full disclosure: I have not installed this font. Please let us know your results